# jQuery.Event('keydown') not working on an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to simulate `keydown` event on input field, the code is running but I don't see the chars in the text field, here is my code:

```
$el.focus();
var keyCodes = _process.value.toCharCode(); // array of keyCodes to insert (e.g [117,118,119])
for(var i = 0, len = keyCodes.length; i < len; i++){
    var e = jQuery.Event('keydown');
    e.which = keyCodes[i];
    $el.trigger(e); // $el is my `input` text field
}
```

This code is not working in Chrome/IE/Firefox... what am I doing wrong? I saw a lot of same example, even in jquery docs...

Comment: That's not how keyboard input works. You're just sending the event to existing JavaScript handlers; it doesn't actually type anything. (If it did, that would be a pretty bad security problem.)

Comment: Thanks.. I just binded the `keydown` event to the input field and it worked